# Margin on Bootstrap affix navigation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, sticky

I created a sticky navigation bar with the Bootstrap Affix plugin.
The navigation bar is located underneath the header. When scrolling the page down, once the navigation reaches the top, it sticks there.
It works fine, so far so good.

However something does not work as I want. At the moment that the navigationbar reaches the top, its position changes from 'static' to 'fixed' (for obvious reasons). Consequence is that the page content under the navigation can not 'see' the navigation bar anymore, from one scrolled pixel to another. (Being fixed, it's moved outside the flow). So from one moment to another, the page content does not see the bottom-margin of the navigation anymore, and it takes the header as its preceding element.

Consequence of that is that the page content suddenly skips a few rows of pixels (the amount equal to the bottom-margin of the navigation) and makes a 'hop'.

See below screenshots, one right before the navigation reaches the top (still static), and one right after it reached the top (fixed)

All in all I find this very understandable, CSS works as it's expected to. However it's not what I want. I want that the page content follows the normal scroll movement, and does not hop over an some distance.

How can I change that?

[image: Navigation static]
[image: Navigation fixed]
        
    
    
    
    Title

```
<body>
<header class="header container">
<h1>Header</h1>
<h2>Tagline</h2>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
</header>
   <nav id="main-navigation" class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">

      <section id="about">
      <h2>About</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec at velit eu leo semper pharetra vitae sed nisl. In elementum neque in urna elementum tristique. Sed malesuada risus justo, ut pellentesque enim vehicula vitae. Quisque a nunc et ligula sagittis ullamcorper. Proin eu faucibus eros, id iaculis felis. Praesent vitae dolor a quam accumsan egestas sit amet et sapien. Praesent tincidunt quam id vestibulum sollicitudin. Ut eget sem a diam tempus tempor. </p>
      <p>In elementum neque in urna elementum tristique. Sed malesuada risus justo, ut pellentesque enim vehicula vitae. Quisque a nunc et ligula sagittis ullamcorper. Proin eu faucibus eros, id iaculis felis. Praesent vitae dolor a quam accumsan egestas</p>
      <p>Nunc tempus egestas massa id cursus. Integer vehicula enim et lacus suscipit, at posuere ante ullamcorper. Mauris condimentum eros in luctus blandit. Nam at nibh dignissim libero dictum lacinia lacinia et neque. In viverra lorem id nulla aliquam, vel laoreet est porttitor. Sed congue tincidunt arcu eget cursus.<br />Quisque aliquam laoreet quam et maximus. Pellentesque maximus ullamcorper ante, a elementum est dapibus at. Nulla feugiat leo sed turpis convallis suscipit vel dictum sapien. Vivamus luctus id nulla sit amet fermentum. Praesent sodales viverra enim ut malesuada. Ut in elit bibendum, mollis dui nec, faucibus enim. Vivamus ullamcorper sed augue at lacinia.</p>
      </section>

       <section id="products">
      <h2>Products</h2>
      <p> Nunc mattis mauris quis diam dictum, non tristique diam congue. Vestibulum tincidunt augue a dui interdum facilisis. Donec sed neque id nunc ullamcorper porta quis vitae nibh. Quisque aliquam laoreet quam et maximus. Pellentesque maximus ullamcorper ante, a elementum est dapibus at. Nulla feugiat leo sed turpis convallis suscipit vel dictum sapien. Vivamus luctus id nulla sit amet fermentum. Praesent sodales viverra enim ut malesuada. Ut in elit bibendum, mollis dui nec, faucibus enim. Vivamus ullamcorper sed augue at lacinia. Nunc tempus egestas massa id cursus. Integer vehicula enim et lacus suscipit, at posuere ante ullamcorper. Mauris condimentum eros in luctus blandit. Nam at nibh dignissim libero dictum lacinia lacinia et neque. In viverra lorem id nulla aliquam, vel laoreet est porttitor. Sed congue tincidunt arcu eget cursus.<br />Quisque aliquam laoreet quam et maximus. Pellentesque maximus ullamcorper ante, a elementum est dapibus at. Nulla feugiat leo sed turpis convallis suscipit vel dictum sapien. Vivamus luctus id nulla sit amet fermentum. Praesent sodales viverra enim ut malesuada. Ut in elit bibendum, mollis dui nec, faucibus enim. Vivamus ullamcorper sed augue at lacinia. Nunc tempus egestas massa id cursus. Integer vehicula enim et lacus suscipit, at posuere ante ullamcorper. Mauris condimentum eros in luctus blandit.</p>
      <p>Curabitur posuere ornare enim. Nullam scelerisque vulputate risus, id consequat odio auctor interdum. Etiam eu ligula ut neque semper aliquam ut eget augue. Fusce in volutpat velit, sit amet gravida ipsum. Sed a consectetur nunc. Sed molestie scelerisque nunc nec pellentesque. Aliquam eget malesuada nulla, ut lobortis est.</p>
      </section>

    </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    @import url("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css");

nav#main-navigation.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
}

nav.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    z-index: 1030;
    width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this issue... Not sure if it helps you now but this is a CSS workaround that works well to prevent the "hop".  The css code is in stylus but you get the picture...

The idea is that the affix bar is already outside the navbar-wrapper div by being absolutely positioned so that there is no "hop" when it's changed to fixed.  The margin-bottom will keep the space for the nav bar spacing. Note that the navbar-wrapper has position relative so that the affix class's absolute position will be relative to it and appear in the div.

```
.navbar-wrapper
 margin-bottom 45px
 position relative    
.affix-top
 position absolute
 top 0
 left 0
 z-index 100
.affix
 position fixed
 top 0
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If this appears to be same in all browsers, you can put

```
nav#main-navigation.navbar {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

this will move menubar little bit to the top,
hope this will solve your problem

Cheers

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. For completeness I created a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Gooly/escewot2/

Comment: its looks like fine here with out even the fix :http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarpg/escewot2/2/

Comment: It works as it should, but the page content still makes the same 'hop'. Check the 'About' header in the content below the navigation. Once the navigation fixes to the top, it suddenly hops up.

Answer (score 0):

@Naveen fix might work - but do you think its semantic fix for this issue.

Comment: Vikky, by looking at the visuals i am suggesting this fix. i am not sure what exactly causing the gap at the top. if can see the page ob browser it easy to give exact fix.